# LyX removing preview block

Tags: floats, lyx, preview

It seems I have lots of questions that either aren't explained anywhere, or that I don't know the right search term to find them! This time, I'm not sure how one is supposed to *remove* an instant preview block from the LyX editor.

I put an instant-preview block around an entire float block, but apparently it can't preview that (which makes sense) so I put one *inside* the float block, which does work, but now my float block is surrounded by a black border in the editor, and I'd like to get rid of that (especially because something about this arrangement of multiple nested previews crashed LyX once earlier, and I'd like it not to crash again). I found the "dissolve inset" button in the context menu, but that only seems to get rid of the float block, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities:

#### Dissolve inset

Dissolve inset (available via right click) does what you want, you just need to be careful where the cursor is placed. Two options for cursor placement that work here:

- *Before* and *outside* the preview inset.
- *After* the figure inset, *inside* the preview inset.

I suppose one could say that dissolve inset acts on the inset to the right of the cursor.

#### Backspace

As scottkosty mentioned in his comment: With the cursor *inside* the preview inset, at the very start (*before* the figure inset), you can hit the backspace key to delete the preview inset.

#### Cut and paste

Select the figure inset, cut it, delete the now empty preview inset, paste the figure inset back in.

In keyboard shortcuts, if you place the cursor inside the outer preview inset, just before the figure inset: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to select the figure. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to cut. <kbd>Del</kbd> (or backspace) to delete empty preview. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste figure back in.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a way to just remove the preview block without doing that, but I suppose that's not too difficult. Thanks!

Comment: @Felthry Updated my answer.

Comment: If the cursor is just inside the preview inset but outside the figure inset, you can do "Backspace".

Comment: @Felthry If this answers your question, please click the "Green checkmark" to accept the answer.

Comment: @scottkosty It wasn't quite satisfactory at first, but now I think it is, so I'm accepting it. Thank you, Torbjørn and Scott!

Comment: @Felthry sounds good, glad that it worked. I don't know of any other method than the ones already mentioned.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'll add that putting the cursor before and outside the preview inset did not produce an option to dissolve inset. I'm not sure why; this was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Felthry Can't say why that would be the case either, unless there's some version difference. I have LyX 2.3.0 (on Linux).

Comment: I'm running LyX 2.2.3 on Windows. Can only assume a version difference. \*shrug*